# window.print is not working in mobile chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4te2ysaw/)

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
        <tbody id="printTbody"><tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>      
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>      
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>        
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>        
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adam</td>
            <td>Johnson</td>        
            <td>67</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>    
    <button onclick="printTablefun()">Print Table</button>
    
    <script>
    function printTablefun()
    {
       var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
       var newWin= window.open("");
       newWin.document.write("<center><h1>Header</h1> </center>");
       newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
       newWin.print();
       newWin.close();
    }
    </script>
```

[image: Print in Android phone chrome browser]

### Print in Android Chrome browser

1. When I tried to print but it's not printing in Android chrome browser
2. It's Just throwing and error
3. But it's working fine in a computer windows chrome

### Solution

1. Please let me know why it's not working in Android chrome browser
2. Please provide me any alternatives instead of window.print()

Comment: window.print() works on chrome mobile and your fiddle is working too.
Did you try to [clear your browing data](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) ?

Comment: I have tried its not working in my android phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=1000');
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
printWindow.document.write('</style>');
printWindow.document.write('</head>');
printWindow.document.write('<body>');
printWindow.document.write("<center>header</center>");
printWindow.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
printWindow.document.write('</body>');
printWindow.document.write('</html>');
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.print();
```

### Description:

1. I have tried like this now its working fine in both computer browser and mobile browser.

Comment: Tested and worked on Android ZKTeco ZKH300. I wonder why this answer got a -1.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in the function `printTablefun()` you have not declared the `newWin` variable,you can add `var` keyword before it. Thanks

Comment: I have tried still its not working in android chrome browser